# Debugging hadoop Wordcount program in eclipse in windows

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Trying to run Wordcount program in hadoop in eclipse (windows 7). and passing these argument in eclipse only

```
E:\hadoop\eclipse-hadoop-pro\workspace-hadoop\WordCountPro\input\word.txt
E:\hadoop\eclipse-hadoop-pro\workspace-hadoop\WordCountPro\output
```

I have created input file in project only like input folder and inside it word.txt file

But it is throughing below excption

```
2015-04-08 15:30:09,947 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2015-04-08 15:30:10,238 ERROR [main] util.Shell (Shell.java:getWinUtilsPath(373)) - Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable E:\hadoop\hadoop-HADOOP_HOME\hadoop-2.6.0\bin\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:363)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.parseStaticMapping(Groups.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:280)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:748)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:621)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.<init>(JobContextImpl.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.<init>(Job.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getInstance(Job.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getInstance(Job.java:206)
    at com.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:52)
2015-04-08 15:30:11,039 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(1049)) - session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
2015-04-08 15:30:11,041 INFO  [main] jvm.JvmMetrics (JvmMetrics.java:init(76)) - Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory file:/E:/hadoop/eclipse-hadoop-pro/workspace-hadoop/WordCountPro/output already exists
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1314)
    at com.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:61)
```

Comment: If you want to ask a completely different question, add a new quesiton. Don't edit a previous question to say something completely different.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul- Actually I have been blocked to ask the new questions. Thats why I have edited the old question.

Comment: I have no idea why you were blocked, but I imagine it was for a good reason, and circumventing it in this way doesn't seem a smart idea.  This question does seem a little obvious. You need to define `spark`. Any Spark tutorial will cover how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt if Hadoop is installed correctly. Check in your machine if all the daemons are running or not.If not, then consider re-checking or re-installing what you are missing.

```
 ERROR [main] util.Shell (Shell.java:getWinUtilsPath(373)) - Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable
```